# What kind of gala fete is The Wolf attending in the early morning?

Tags: pulp-fiction

When Winston Wolf is first contacted in *Pulp Fiction*, he is seen taking the phone call alone in a bedroom of a house where there are several middle-aged adults also dressed formally.  (Winston Wolf is wearing a proper tuxedo)

This all happens during an hour where Bonnie has yet to return (1.5 hours out) from her graveyard shift at the hospital.  My mother also was a nurse who worked the graveyard shift, and would routinely return at 7:30am.

Even if the time is 8am, what kind of party could this be?

Comment: Timestamp? My first guess would be one of those parties with a large bowl of white powder on the coffee table, but I'd like to have another look ;)

Comment: Is there a timestamp?  I just watched a heavily edited version, didn't notice if any were shown.

Comment: Timestamp… ie number of minutes since start of movie, so we can find the scene without having to skim it all to find it

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8B1p1zPFo7w